# Graphing percent of whole based on multiple criteria

Tags: r, plyr

Update:
If anyone is wondering, both answers work.  They will both achieve a summary table, much like you would create if emulating Sumifs in Excel. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again to both of you.

I have a data frame (df) that looks something like this, but with more products.
`df$Yr` is based on a cutoff date >= 3/2012

```
Product      Classif         Yr     Revenue
a            paid_yes      TRUE     25
a            paid_yes      TRUE     20
a            paid_yes      TRUE     35
a            paid_yes      FALSE    20
a            paid_yes      FALSE    30
a            paid_yes      FALSE    30
a            paid_partial  TRUE     15
a            paid_partial  TRUE     15
a            paid_partial  FALSE    18
a            leased        TRUE     12
a            leased        TRUE     12
a            leased        FALSE    14
a            Other         TRUE     27
a            Other         FALSE    30
a            Other         TRUE     25
a            Other         FALSE    22
a            Other         TRUE     32
a            Other         FALSE    30
a            Other         TRUE     24
a            Other         FALSE    27
b            paid_yes      TRUE     45
b            paid_yes      FALSE    32
b            paid_yes      TRUE     35
b            paid_yes      FALSE    39
b            paid_partial  FALSE    42
b            paid_partial  FALSE    45
b            paid_partial  TRUE     47
b            paid_partial  FALSE    33
b            paid_partial  FALSE    28
b            leased        TRUE     48
b            leased        FALSE    46
b            leased        FALSE    45
b            leased        TRUE     37
b            leased        FALSE    33
b            leased        TRUE     46
b            leased        FALSE    44
b            Other         TRUE     49
b            Other         FALSE    45
b            Other         TRUE     43
b            Other         FALSE    39
```

I am attempting to do a facet scatter plot, by product (a, b, c, etc).
I want my y axis to be `df$Classif`, and x axis to be the percentage of total `Revenue` by `Product`, within each `Yr`.
Or in other words, what percentage of total revenue for a product given a certain year, does each classification account for?

I want my summary frame to look something like...

```
Product      Classif         Yr     perc.rev
a            paid_yes      TRUE     .332
a            paid_partial  TRUE     .123
a            leased        TRUE     .099
a            Other         TRUE     .446
```

Where each perc.rev adds up to 100% given a `Product`, `Classif`, and `Yr`

I have attempted to get my summary data set/column with the following code:

```
df.perc <- ddply(df, .(Product, Classif, Yr), summarise,
               perc.rev = sum(Revenue)/count(Classif))
```

The resultant data frame gives me the *average* revenue by `Product`, `Classif`, and `Yr`.  What I need is *percentage* of revenue generated by a given `Classif` , compared to ALL `Classif` - by `Product` and by `Year`

I am pretty sure I just need some help with my perc.rev formula, or the `.variables` section of `ddply`.  I am used to Excel and would normally use 2 sumifs formulas, but am not sure how to express what I need to do here in an R function.

Comment: Does the example come from that data? If so, how did you exactly compute the .332 of (a,paid_yes,TRUE)?

Comment: I created the data set provided at the top, then calculated the output/summary data frame in Excel using sumifs. : )  I actually tacked on the 2 in .332

Comment: But what would be the numbers and operations involved...I don't see where that .332 came from

Comment: ah I think I know what you mean.  So it would be the sum of all revenue for `Product: a, Classif: paid_yes, Yr: True` divided by the sum of all revenue for `Product: a, Yr: True`

Comment: Then the `perc.rev` should be (80,30,24,108)/242=(.331,.214,.099,.446), which is slightly different. Then I think you should rewrite the question: "perc.rev adds up to 100% given a Product and Yr" (remove Classif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do a two pass process that adds a by-Product 'total' using `ave(...,...,sum)`, and then a by-Classif percentage with

```
<strike>apply( ..., ..., function(x) x["Classif"]/x['total"] )<\strike>
```

---

Edit: (I haven't figured out how this deserved a check, but will now try to fix) That second part was too cryptic and probably simply wrong. Might have been potentially correctable changing x["Classif"] to x["Revenue"] but I think `apply` was the wrong function altogether .

The request was for "what percentage of total revenue for a product given a certain year, does each classification account for" ...and  "Where each perc.rev adds up to 100% given a Product, Classif, and Yr". Now clearly the output implied that at least that second part should have read "Where each perc.rev adds up to 100% given a Product and Yr." (omitting the Classif).

```
dfrm$total <- ave(dfrm$Revenue, dfrm$Product, dfrm$Yr, FUN=sum)
dfrm$prod.yr.prop <- dfrm$Revenue/dfrm$total
aggregate(dfrm$prod.yr.prop, list(class=dfrm$Classif, Yr=dfrm$Yr, Prod=dfrm$Product), FUN=sum)
          class    Yr Prod          x
1        leased FALSE    a 0.06334842
2         Other FALSE    a 0.49321267
3  paid_partial FALSE    a 0.08144796
4      paid_yes FALSE    a 0.36199095
5        leased  TRUE    a 0.09917355
6         Other  TRUE    a 0.44628099
7  paid_partial  TRUE    a 0.12396694
8      paid_yes  TRUE    a 0.33057851
9        leased FALSE    b 0.35668790
10        Other FALSE    b 0.17834395
11 paid_partial FALSE    b 0.31422505
12     paid_yes FALSE    b 0.15074310
13       leased  TRUE    b 0.37428571
14        Other  TRUE    b 0.26285714
15 paid_partial  TRUE    b 0.13428571
16     paid_yes  TRUE    b 0.22857143
```

This does a within-Product-Yr totalling and then calculates a Classif-specificproportion within those groupings.

Comment: Indeed, here is the more elegant solution :-) Didn't know the `ave` function. Cheers!

Comment: Yes. `tapply` will collapse functional results within categories, but `ave` lets you spread the information across every entry in categories.

Comment: @DWin - I am having trouble passing the correct arguments to ave.  I'm assuming you mean something like `total <- ave(df$Product, df$Yr, sum)` and then plugging that into the `apply()` function.  But then again, you probably don't because this produces an error : )  Could you elaborate on how you would make this work?

Comment: `ave` requires that its function argument be named "FUN=sum"

Comment: it should be `ave(df$Revenue, df$Product, df$Yr, FUN=sum)`

Comment: I've been trying to get DWin's solution to work.  I really like the use of `ave`, but I have not been able to work around an error I get from apply.  So with `total <- ave(df$Revenue, df$Product, df$Yr, FUN = sum)` followed by `apply(X = df, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) x["Classif"]/x["total"])`  the error I continue to get is traced to `function(x)`, with the following message `non-numeric argument to binary operator`.  I have tried to run a few different ways, but results are the same.  If I have negative values in some the `df$Revenue` column, could this produce the error?

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to `plyr`, so there might be a more elegant solution. First, store the total count for each `(Product, Yr)` combination. Then run `ddply`:

```
counts <- ddply(df, .(Product, Yr), summarise, count=sum(Revenue))
ddply(df, .(Product, Classif, Yr), summarise,
  perc.rev=sum(Revenue)/counts$count[counts$Product==Product[1] & counts$Yr==Yr[1]])
```

Which gives

```
   Product      Classif    Yr   perc.rev
1        a       leased FALSE 0.06334842
2        a       leased  TRUE 0.09917355
3        a        Other FALSE 0.49321267
4        a        Other  TRUE 0.44628099
5        a paid_partial FALSE 0.08144796
6        a paid_partial  TRUE 0.12396694
7        a     paid_yes FALSE 0.36199095
8        a     paid_yes  TRUE 0.33057851
9        b       leased FALSE 0.35668790
10       b       leased  TRUE 0.37428571
11       b        Other FALSE 0.17834395
12       b        Other  TRUE 0.26285714
13       b paid_partial FALSE 0.31422505
14       b paid_partial  TRUE 0.13428571
15       b     paid_yes FALSE 0.15074310
16       b     paid_yes  TRUE 0.22857143
```

Comment: I'm attempting to work out your solution, but am not sure about the second part.  When executing the `counts` assignment, I get an understandable result (thank you for this, I can see myself using that a lot).  However, I am unsure how to use the second ddply function - and am getting a strange result.  Output looks like
`1        a       leased  FALSE 0.06334842` but then beneath each classification is a duplicated NA record. `2        a       leased  FALSE NA`

Comment: Nevermind, just had to tack on `na.exclude` ! But I do have another question about the subset arguments `Product[1]` and `Yr[1]`.  What is the 1 referencing?

Comment: For what I saw, `Product` and `Yr` have as many elements as the combination in the data.frame. For instance, `(a,paid_yes,TRUE)` appears 3 times. If you remove `[1]` it throws some warnings saying that you're comparing many elements at the same time. Using `[1]` just uses the first one (the other two are just the same)